# How do you create multiple "if" statements?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I need help in my java script.
I want to create if then if else and last else... but it won't work :(

```
if(fallingFrame >= fallingSpeed) {
    if(floor.contains(pt1) || floor.contains(pt2) || floatFloor.contains(pt1) || floatFloor.contains(pt2) || tLPF.contains(pt1) || tLPF.contains(pt2) ) {
        //if (isPlayerOnFloor() || IsPlayerOnFloor()) {
        falling = false;
        if(floatFloor.contains(pt1) || floatFloor.contains(pt2)) {
            character.y = main.height - floatFloorHeight - characterheight;
        }
        if else
        {
            character.y = main.height - floorheight - characterheight;

        }
    else (tLPF.contains(pt1) || tLPF.contains(pt2)) {
            character.y = main.height - tLPFHeight - characterheight;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Basic tutorial will really help you.

Comment: it's `else if` not `if else`.

Answer (score 5):

```
if (a == b) {
  ... do this ...
} else if (a == b+1) {  // <---- I believe you're looking for this!
  ... do that ...
} else {
  ... do something generic! ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be "else if", not "if else".

Also you need another condition in there.  "else if" what?  What you basically want to say is:

1. "if this", do some stuff.
2. "if something else", do something else.
3. "in all other cases", do some default action.